# Eclipse - Access denied when trying to add files to Program Arguments

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a folder of files that I am trying to add to the program arguments in eclipse, but when I try to execute the program I get the error:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: [path] (Access is denied)

I am pasting the path into the program arguments field under the arguments tab in run configuration. So far I've tried putting a folder in the project directory, my documents and the desktop but it keeps saying "Access is denied." I am doing this all on my laptop where I am the administrator. Thanks for any help.

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that. Win7

Comment: where is your project directory located? you can try to add the folder just in drive c:\.  at least desktop and documents are somehow restricted (i don't know exactly how)

Comment: The project is located in my workspace in my users folder. I tried adding the folder with the files into C:\temp, but it still says Access Denied

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your folder and set the correct permission.

Comment: The permissions for the system are all set to allow

Answer (score 0):

I put the files in the directory with the src folder and it worked. Note, you must put the file extension in the arguments field or it won't work.